# Why doesn't $\mu$ change during a phase transition?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, physical-chemistry, chemical-potential

I am learning about (first-order) phase transitions from Callen's Chapter 9 and am a bit baffled about something. Some of the confusion may be related to my question 1) [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/771947/why-is-vapor-pressure-well-defined), too.

In the below, I bold each of my questions.

Consider the equilibrium that exists between two phases of a single-component substance at some $(P,T)$. The relevant thermodynamic variables are $(P,T,N_g,N_l)$, where $g,l$ denote the moles in each phase (I take these as liquid and gas just for simplicity, though it's irrelevant). The condition for equilibrium is that
$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial N_g} \equiv \mu_g = \mu_l = \frac{\partial G}{\partial N_l}.$$
Now the $\mu$ are, in general (and as with any derivative of a fundamental equation like $G$), functions of $(P,T,N_g,N_l)$. Now suppose we are have "just arrived" at equilibrium from the liquid side, so that $N = N_l$. It's probably better to discuss in terms of mole fraction, so we characterize this point as $x_l = 1$. **If there were no external stimuli, the system would remain at $x_l = 1$, right?**

Now suppose such a stimulus exists, so that we proceed to some $x_l <1, x_g > 0$. **Since the $\mu_i$ are functions of the $N_j$, wouldn't we generally expect the $\mu$ to change (and therefore the equilibrium $\mu_g = \mu_l$ condition to be violated)?** Or is the idea that, at phase equilibrium, not only is it the case that
$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial N_g} \equiv \mu_g = \mu_l = \frac{\partial G}{\partial N_l}$$
but also that, while at the fixed $(T,P)$ on the coexistence curve,
$$\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial N_i\partial N_j}  = 0$$
for all possible $(i,j)$? I have not yet seen Callen state this, but perhaps he thinks this obvious/that I should be clever enough to know this. If so, I am glad I live in a time when I can ask questions like this on Physics SE!

In the end, I suppose my question is about understanding how we can be in equilibrium for all $x_l \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Why do you assume $\mu$ depends on $N$? Usually $G=\mu N$ and $\mu$ is assumed to be function of $T,P$ (different function for liquid, and different function for gas).

Comment: @JánLalinský Because a priori any derivative of a fundamental relation is a function of all the independent variables in that fundamental relation. My question could be construed as asking why that’s not true in the particular case of $\mu$, but also I don’t think your statement is true. $\mu$ surely depends on $N$ in many systems, no? A system of $N$ electrons, for example?

Comment: Ignoring surface energy, internal energy is extensive function of $S,V,N$, so we have $U = TS - PV + \mu N$, where $\mu$ does not depend on $N$.

Comment: Why does writing $U$ in the Euler form suggest $\mu$ not a function of $N$? After all, $T$ still depends on $S$ in general? @JánLalinský

Comment: When we write down $U = TS - PV + \mu N$, this is in context where $U$ is homogeneous function of first degree of variables $S,V,N$, that is, $U(kS,kV,kN) = kU(S,V,N)$. This is possible only if $\mu$ does not depend on any extensive variable $S,V,N$.

Comment: $\mu$ is the Gibbs energy per unit mole. In context where all energies for fixed intensive state (T,P) are linear functions of total number of particles (surface energy is negligible), extensive state variable per unit mole, such as $\mu$, does not depend on total number of moles.

Comment: Are you arguing as follows? Since $\mu = G/N$ and since $G$ itself is homogenous because it's a Lgendre transform of $U$ which is homogeneous (so $G(T,P,N) = NG(T,P,1)$ and thus $\mu = G(T,P,1)$ is independent of $N$? @JánLalinský

Comment: If so, how would you generalize this when $G$ depends on $N_g$ and $N_l$ (i.e. on the amount in both phases) a priori?

Comment: Yes. For liquid $\mu_l = G_l/N_l$ and thus does not depend on $N_l$. Similarly for the gas.

Comment: In system with liquid and gas we arrive at $G = \mu_l N_l + \mu_vN_v$, so how do you find that that means there's no dependence on either $N_l$ or $N_v$ for either $\mu$? @JánLalinský

Comment: Because $G$ is homogeneous function of first degree of $N_l,N_g$, and thus both  $\mu_l,\mu_g$ are intensive functions of $T,P$, independent of $N_l,N_g$. When $N_l,N_g$ change at fixed $(T,P)$, then $G$ changes, but $\mu_l,\mu_g$ do not.

Comment: If you change $N_l,N_g$ in such a way that $(T,P)$ changes, then $(\mu_l,\mu_g)$ will change. In this sense, $\mu_l,\mu_g$ depend on $N_l,N_g$.

Comment: I think I see @JánLalinský, if you want to put that as an answer I will accept.

Comment: OK I've put that into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Usually for single phase $G=\mu N$ and $\mu$ is assumed to be function of $T,P$ (different function for liquid, and different function for gas).

When we write down $U=TS−PV+\mu N$, this is in context where $U$ does not have contribution due to surface energy. It is then homogeneous function of first degree of variables $S,V,N$, that is, $U(kS,kV,kN)=kU(S,V,N)$. This is possible only if $\mu$ does not depend on any extensive variable $S,V,N$ (just as $T,P$ don't).

Because $G = \mu_l N_l + \mu_g N_g$ is homogeneous function of first degree of $N_l,N_g$, both $\mu_l, \mu_g$ are intensive functions of $T,P$ independent of $N_l,N_g$. When $N_l,N_g$ change at fixed $(T,P)$, then $G$ changes, but $\mu_l,\mu_g$ do not.

If you change $N_l,N_g$ in such a way that $(T,P)$ changes, then $(\mu_l,\mu_g)$ will change. In this sense, $\mu_l,\mu_g$ depend on $N_l,N_g$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason for your "bafflement" is the physicist's unforgivable (?) use of the same notation for two different functions having the same value, here $\mu$. You can always write that $U=TS-pV+\mu N$, but if you write that $$dU=TdS-pdV+\mu dN \tag{1}$$ then the $\mu$ in the differential form  (1) is $\mu = f_u(S,V,N)$ for some function $f_u$ of the variables of $S,V,N$ and this $f_u$ being representative of an intensive is a homogeneous function of $0$ order, that is $f_u(S,V,N)= f_u(kS,kV,kN)$ for an arbitrary scalar multiplier $k$. This $f_u$ can depend explicitly on $N$, for example if it is a function say $f_u(S,V,N)=f_1(\tfrac{S^2}{VN})$, which is homogeneous $0$ order.

Now if you introduce the Gibbs potential via the Legendre transform,

$$dG=-SdT+pdV+\mu dN \tag{2}$$
then the "$\mu$" in (2) is a completely different function from the "$\mu$" in (1). The latter is $\mu = f_g(T,p, N)$ and it can only be of homogenous $0$ order if it is *independent* of the variable $N$. For this function there is no such combination of the variables $T,p,N$ that will get $f_g(T, p, N) = f_g(T, p, kN)$ unless $f_g(T,p, N)=g(T,p)$.

In general, if there there is only a single extensive variable, $z_0$, of a function $r$ representing an intensive quantity, say, $r=(z_0, z_1,z_2,...)$ and its other independent parameters are intensives, so that $r=(z_0, z_1,z_2,...)= r(kz_0, z_1,z_2,...)$ then $r$ is independent of $z_0$ but it can depend on more than *one* extensives simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you! The sentence "For this function there is no such combination of the variables..." gets me incredibly close to understanding, except that I'm not sure how to generalize to the case of their being two intensive variables! For example, in phase equilibrium (say between solid and liquid) we in fact have, a priori, that $\mu = f_g(T,p, N_s, N_l)$. How do you go about arguing in this case that $\mu = g(T,p)$ nevertheless?

Comment: I can argue indirectly: $dU=TdS-pdV+\mu dN$ or $dG=-SdT+Vdp+\mu dN$ is a single phase equation, each phase has its own "$\mu$", there is a $\mu_{\ell}=f_{\ell}(T,p)$ and another $\mu_{s}=f_{s}(T,p)$ because there is $U_{ell}$ and $U_{s}$ *whose* sum is that of the  total 2-phase energy, and the two phases are to be in equilibrium.